# HBase: Column Family TTL

Tags: hbase, ttl

According with HBase specs :

> *"ColumnFamilies can set a TTL length in seconds, and HBase will automatically delete rows once the expiration time is reached. This
>   applies to all versions of a row - even the current one. The TTL time
>   encoded in the HBase for the row is specified in UTC."*

Specifically what I'm not understanding is this sentence "Once the expiration time is reached"...of what? All versions of all cells? at least one version of one cell?

Suppose I have a table which has a column family with TTL set to X.

- I'm inserting a cell with timestamp 1: what is the expiry date of this row? 1 + X?
- Next, I'm inserting another cell (using the same row key) with timestamp 2: what is the expiry date of the entire row? Still 1 + X or 2 + X?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That appears to be a typo in the HBase reference guide. It should say "cell", not "row"; a row has no built-in timestamp other than the timestamp of its cells.

Comment: Also, you should open a JIRA for this, or supply a doc patch if you feel so inclined: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE

Comment: Thank you for your response. So that means, assuming I have a row with two cells (each one has a different timestamp), the row will be "deleted" gradually (First the oldest cell, then in a second momemnt the youngest one)?

Comment: @Andrea I personally tested it by setting the TTL to 60 seconds and insert 6 values into one cell every 10 seconds, and found they were deleted gradually -- deleted one by one every 10 seconds.